# on click notification how to close activity before opening it, if it is running already

Tags: android

I have written a piece of code to start an activity on click notification. But if that activity is already open (visible) then I want to close that activity first before opening it again. Please tell how can I do that?

**This is code of how I am generating notification:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewReminders.class);
intent.putExtra("CALLER","GenNot");
intent.putExtra("ID",notification_id);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
mBuilder.setTicker("Smart Locator");
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
mBuilder.setContentTitle(name);
DetailsContainer dc = new LocationDetails(context).getDetails(location);
mBuilder.setContentText(date +", "+dc.area+" "+dc.locality);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(document_id, notification_id, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: By "running", do you mean running in foreground?

Comment: @jaibatrik I have edited my question. Please see it now.

Comment: You should set your activity `launchMode` to `singleTop` in manifest and then implement `onNewIntent` in it.  This way, when you click the notification, if your activity is already in foreground, then it won't be launched again but instead its `onNewIntent` method would be called.

Comment: Aleks G's suggestion should help you, but perhaps you could explain in your question *why* you need to close the Activity before launching it again. There might be a better way to solve the problem you're having.