# close activity before opening it on clicking notification

Tags: android

I am opening an activity on clicking notification, that is working fine. But if that activity (which I am opening on clicking notification) is already open (user has opened it) then I want to close it before opening it as a result of clicking notification. So how can I do that. Please help.

**Code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewReminders.class);
        intent.putExtra("CALLER","GenNot");
        intent.putExtra("ID",notification_id);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [on click notification how to close activity before opening it, if it is running already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327580/on-click-notification-how-to-close-activity-before-opening-it-if-it-is-running)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with setting the following flags

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: this prevents activity from opening if it is open already, but I want to close it and then open it.

Comment: I have putted an alternative please try with new

Comment: yes it worked. but is there any way to perform action on opened activity instead of opening it again?

Comment: Yes. there is another way that is LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: please tell how can I use that?

Comment: You need to open as new activity every time click for showing updated data. am i right?